# Laravel Reading files in storage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have saved images in a file in the storage. I would like to get the files saved into an array using exec command in the controller and then pass the array into the blade. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: "_I would like to get the files saved into an array_" And have you done anything yet to get there? Can we see your code? Why `exec()`?

Comment: See [ask] and make sure you take the [tour]. The idea is to tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and show what results you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$images= [];
// $filesInFolder = \File::files('images'); getting files from the folder
$files =  file_get_contents( 'filename' ); // replace here the filename with you full path of the file

foreach($files as $path)
{
   $images[] = pathinfo($path);
}
```

Then you can pass the images/files in your blade.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your requirement to read the files names from a file. I am not sure you wish like that